# How to create a column that groups all values from column into list that fall between values of different columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames that look like this:

```
unit      start    stop
A      0.0    8.15
B      9.18   11.98
A     13.07   13.80
B     13.82   15.00
A     16.46   17.58
```

df_2

```
time    other_data
1            5
2            5
3            6
4            10
5            5
6            2
7            1
8            5
9            5
10           7
11           5
12           5
13           5
14           10
15           5
16           4
17           4
18           4
```

How do I append all values from df_2.other_data where df_2.time falls in between df_1.start and df_1.stop into a list (or array)? For example, all the values of df_2.other_data where df_2.time falls between df_1.start and df_1.stop for row 1 would be [5, 5, 6, 10, 5, 2, 1 5].

The desired df will look as below.

```
unit      start    stop   other_data_list
A      0.0    8.15          [5,5,6,10,5,2,1,5]
B      9.18   11.98         [5,7,5]
A     13.07   13.80         [5] 
B     13.82   15.00         [5,10,5]
A     16.46   17.58         [4,4]
```

Comment: You should be able to join the two dataframes and then use `.groupby()`

Comment: Why do you get a 5 between 13.07 and 13.80? Should't that be empty? There are also other values which does not fall in between but are added to the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
df1['other'] = df1.apply(lambda row : df2['other_data'].loc[(df2['time'] > row['start']) & (df2['time'] < row['stop'])].tolist(), axis=1)
```

Output is, using your sample datafames:

```
  unit  start   stop                      other
0    A   0.00   8.15  [5, 5, 6, 10, 5, 2, 1, 5]
1    B   9.18  11.98                     [7, 5]
2    A  13.07  13.80                         []
3    B  13.82  15.00                       [10]
4    A  16.46  17.58                        [4]
```

For each row of `df1`, with `apply` you can select the desired values in `df2`. Convert the selection to a `list` using the `tolist()` method of pandas.Series, otherwise you will get a `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed`.